# C++11 function signature with variadic std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a function that takes an `std::function` which returns an it and might get any number of parameters.

I've tried the following but it doesn't compile and I can't understand what the error means.

```
template <typename ...Args>
void ThrowOnError(std::function<int(Args...)> func, Args... args)
{
    int err = func(args...);
    if (err < 0)
        throw std::exception();
}

int f()
{
    return 42;
}

int f(int x)
{
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    ThrowOnError(f);
    ThrowOnError(f, 1);
}
```

I tried moving the templated function to header but it didn't work, also if I comment out the `f(int x)` function and only leave the call with only `f` , I still get a `no matching overloaded function found` and `'void ThrowOnError(std::function<int(Args...)>,Args...)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<int(Args...)>' from 'int (int)'`

What is the problem here? what am I missing in the function?

P.S - I would like an answer which takes an `std::function` if possible, and not add another typename for the functor type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing a `std::function` as a parameter and deduction can't take place.
In other there, to assign the function to the `std::function`, you must know the actual type. To find it, deduction must happen. For deduction to happen you should first assign the function pointer to the `std::function`, but the type of the latter is unknown (because deduction didn't take place yet).
So on in a loop.

Moreover, when you do this:

```
ThrowOnError(f);
```

It's impossible for the compiler to know what `f` you want to use.
You should rather do something like this:

```
ThrowOnError(std::function<int()>{static_cast<int(*)()>(f)});
```

Or this (if you accept to use another template parameter for the functor):

```
ThrowOnError(static_cast<int(*)()>(f));
```

This way you are picking the right function up from the overload set explicitly and the compiler has not to guess your intentions.
As mentioned, the latter would work fine if you accept to modify also the `ThrowOnError` function as it follows:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void ThrowOnError(F func, Args... args)
{
    int err = func(args...);
    if (err < 0)
        throw std::exception();
}
```

Or even better:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void ThrowOnError(F &&func, Args&&... args)
{
    int err = std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (err < 0)
        throw std::exception();
}
```

Comment: OK, but this doesn't work with a `typename F, typename... Args` as well. how can it be accomplished?

Comment: @ZivS Added more details.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Regarding your edit: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms

Comment: @ZivS Oho, interesting. I'm used to reading it as _a standard function_, so _an_ doesn't sound good. Sorry. Problems of non-native speakers. :-)

Comment: I'm used to calling it S.T.D :) Thanks for your help with the question